# Metrics exporter

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

Is there a way to export metrics to Prometheus about state or checkpoint sizes per operator? I know that I can find this values from the Flink Dashboard, but I need to have all the metrics in just one Grafana board with Prometheus, hoping this is possible.

I want something like this from flink dashboard but in Grafana:

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The summary data values about checkpointing are reported as job metrics -- https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html#checkpointing -- but I believe the per-subtask checkpointing details are only available via the REST api.